# Ebay oauth "Input request parameters are invalid." getting user consent

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, ebay-api

```
https://auth.sandbox.ebay.com/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=${clientID}
&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/ebay/callback
&response_type=code
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.ebay.com%2Foauth%2Fscope%2Fsell%40user
```

I keep receiving this error: {"error_id":"invalid_request","error_description":"Input request parameters are invalid.","http_status_code":400}

I am following instructions from this site [here](https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=5075)

Please can anyone explain why I am getting this error?

Comment: did you find out what happened? having the same issue with php oauth2 client

Comment: invalid_request – The request is missing a parameter so the server can’t proceed with the request. This may also be returned if the request includes an unsupported parameter or repeats a parameter.

This is [unsuccessfull response](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-response/) 

You have missed `$client_secret = 'ebay_client_secret'`

Hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

invalid_request – The request is missing a parameter so the server can’t proceed with the request. This may also be returned if the request includes an unsupported parameter or repeats a parameter.

This is [unsuccessfull response](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-response/) of OAuth

You have missed `$client_secret = 'ebay_client_secret'` Please add that to your code. Hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your `RuName` for the `redirect_uri` parameter.

> The requests to get access tokens require a redirect_url value that the service uses for authorization, as well as a URL to redirect the user to after they've complete the permissions grant request. Instead of a URL, the eBay services require a custom RuName value that eBay generates and assigns to your application.

Instructions for setting this up can be found [here](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-redirect-uri.html).